# Why do I have to reload to see any questions for a search?

Tags: bug, search

On first doing a search on SO, I get no results.

> [image: Screenshot of the page showing no questions]

Reloading it then gives the proper few million hits.

Here the search-query I used (Most popular 10 tags):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20c%23%20or%20javascript%20or%20php%20or%20android%20or%20jquery%20or%20python%20or%20c%2b%2b%20or%20html%20or%20mysql

Pasted from the search-box:

`[java] or [c#] or [javascript] or [php] or [android] or [jquery] or [python] or [c++] or [html] or [mysql]`

BTW: I tested with fully-updated IE11.

Comment: This also happens to me, [often](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284939/901048).

Comment: Frequently happening to me as well! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305734/getting-a-lot-of-blank-pages-but-refresh-fixes-it

Answer (score 4):

That combination of tags is causing the first query to time out when querying the combination of those tags. We respond promptly, but let the query continue and complete - including caching the result. When you reload, you are hitting the cache, so getting an immediate response. I will investigate how often this is happening.

Comment: Now that's a prompt response. Thanks. (Now if we could get instant solutions to our most difficult questions, always, guaranteed...)

Comment: It happens only occasionally for me, but once the tag page is loaded I rarely need to reload anyway, thanks to live refresh.

Comment: I used the get the "Oops" page with a query like that all the time, ~2+ years ago.  Not sure if that was necessarily bad, I knew what went wrong :)

Comment: @MarcGravell It happens to me all the time. My query is c# or asp.net or linq or generics or .net or best-practices or model-view-controller or asp.net-mvc or reflection or attributes or codedom or code-golf or jquery or wcf or puzzle or delegates or anonymous-types or dynamic or regex or ajax or multithreading or sql or linq-to-xml or linq-to-objects or algorithm or marklogic

Comment: This problem is happening to me several times a day.