# Tab 'featured' shows as 0, but clicking on it resolves to 407

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I just noticed that the 'featured' tab on the SO homepage shows as '0':

[image: homepage tab interesting]

After clicking on the tab, the number is '407':

[image: homepage tab featured]

Why is that?

Comment: Ssst, that's so we can keep those to ourselves. Don't go spreading that information around.

Comment: This is usually caused by a timeout on the query on the server; e.g. due to load the query took longer than the page rendering was willing to wait for.

Comment: Clearly it drew additional attention to the featured questions for you.  SUCCESS!!

Comment: @psubsee2003 I saw that question, but the screenshot from the question you linked to shows 0 where mine shows 407

Comment: @msrd0 effectively, it is still related to the same bug.  If you look at the comments, multiple users are having different issues with the featured tab, so it would appear to be an on-going issue with the tab itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by a timeout on the query on the server; e.g. due to load the query took longer than the page rendering was willing to wait for. Rather than have you wait longer, 0 is shown instead.

Wait a minute or 2, when the query succeeds (it is not cancelled) the result is cached and used the next time the page is rendered.

Also see [Why do I have to reload to see any questions for a search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271287/why-do-i-have-to-reload-to-see-any-questions-for-a-search)

Comment: [http://shouldiblamecaching.com/](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).