# linking directly to tag page sometimes presents empty list of questions

Tags: bug

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript*

I keep that page in a bookmark, because it's the questions I'm usually most interested in. (Note the asterisk after `javascript`, in case I want to catch multiple tags at once.)

Sometimes -- not always, or even often -- when I load the URL, it comes up blank: [image]

But every time (so far), if I reload the page, it populates it with the expected questions.