# Getting a lot of blank pages but refresh fixes it

Tags: bug, status-deferred

I have a link that I use to get the most relevant posts that I feel comfortable answering. Fairly frequently I get back that 0 questions are tagged. A simple refresh fixes the problem, but it is becoming quite the thing to refresh every 3 or 4 visits to the link.

The link I am using is all `or` tags so there really should *never* be any times that there are 0 questions tagged. In this example, there just happens to be a new question with activity, but most of the time it's completely empty page.

[Here is the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-2.7+or+python-2.x+or+python3-4+or+python-3.x+or+django+or+pycharm+or+django-models+or+django-queryset+or+django-rest-framework+or+twisted+or+rabbitmq?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Is this a bug?

[image: Borked links]

**Edit:** I have updated the link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-2.7+or+python-3.x+or+django+or+pycharm+or+django-models+or+django-queryset+or+django-rest-framework+or+twisted+or+rabbitmq?sort=newest&pageSize=50) and but the issue still remains.

**Edit 10/31/15:** Just updating that the issue still remains. I am currently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-2.7+or+python-3.x+or+django+or+pycharm+or+django-models+or+django-queryset+or+django-rest-framework+or+twisted+or+rabbitmq?sort=newest&pageSize=50) link which is really similar to the one before but with 2 less tags.

Comment: possibly related [MSE bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261422/280467)?  The behavior for the tags returning empty results but feeding new questions correctly is the same.

Comment: Yes, it may be related. I have continuously tried to remove some of the tags I am using but at the same time there a few I want to add into this query to try and make it more relevant.

Comment: It's exactly as @Cerberus describes in his answers. As part of [tag:new-nav] we're working on improving tag engine performance.

Comment: That issue is a good year old...

Answer (score 4):

This is a very specific (and quite large) query that probably takes a moment to run, server-side.

I think the server just doesn't have enough time to get the results and return them before the page loads, each time the cached query expires.

By the time you refresh, the search is cached and easily returned.

If that's the case, your only option is to drop some redundant / low traffic tags, to try and speed up the query a bit.

Comment: I'm curious to see whether other users can reproduce the problem, now, since I just opened the link. When I first opened the link, the results were indeed empty.

Comment: I couldn't repro but your analysis is probably correct.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it just now. Which means the query is probably cached again.

Comment: That is an interesting take on the issue. I will look over each tag and see if I really need all of them and will cut out any low traffic tags. Could a tag with 0 questions tagged cause the issue? The `python3-4` tag apparently doesn't have any questions tagged.